# Why doesn't a nested flexbox grow to full width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following HTML/CSS:

```html
<div style="display: flex; background-color: yellow;">
  <div style="display: flex;background-color: lightblue;">i am a NESTED flexbox</div>
</div>
```

This ends up as
[image]

Note how the nested flexbox (lightblue background color) does not fill the complete width, while the outer flexbox (yellow background) does.

Why doesn't a nested flexbox container grow to the full width of the parent?

**Hint**: I know I can fix it with `flex: 1`, but the question is about understanding why it behaves like this, not how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightblue div is actually a [flex ***item***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flex_Item). The [default properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#formal_definition) of flex items are:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
```

So the item won't grow to fill the remaining space, it would shrink, and *look at my width or height property* for basis.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested div-block (lightblue background color) only takes up the space (width) it needs. You can see this by doubling the text of the nested block.

It's a matter of default behavior and context formatting:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers

If you want it to take the full width then you have the choice to add `width: 100%;` or `flex:1` in the CSS of the nested div.

Comment: I understand that, but why does the nested flexbox behaves different than the outer one? The outer one grows to the available space, the inner one only to it's content size, not to the available space.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, my fault while creating the reduced example ): Will accept the answer from Salman, as he delivers the flex item properties explaining the behaviour, sorry for not providing the correct sample in the first place, my fault!

Comment: @stefanatwpf: it is indeed as zerbene outdated: it is because by default settings child elements of a flexbox container 'only takes up the space (width) it needs'. It is really as simple ... ;-)

Comment: @Brebber you are right, but I find the answer from Salman more clear/detailed, giving the flex item default properties. both answers are somehow correct though :-)